# MUI React - Override SvgIcon color doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using MUI (version 5) on React.

I'm trying to override the icon color for the Error Alert using General StylesOverrides.

I managed to change the color on the Alert component, but I can't find the way to do it for the icon that is in the Alert

In my Overrides Theme this is my code:

```
const theme = createTheme({
 components: {
      MuiAlert: { // These changes are working
        styleOverrides: {
          standardError: {
            backgroundColor: colors.error.light,
            color: colors.error.dark,
            border: '4px solid',
            borderColor: colors.error.dark,
          }
        }
      },
      MuiSvgIcon: { // These changes are not working
        styleOverrides: {
          ErrorOutlineIcon: {
            htmlColor:'#000000',
            main:'#fff000'
          }
        }
      }
    },
})
```

This is the documentation on the MUI website https://mui.com/material-ui/api/svg-icon/ but I'm missing something.

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

To change the icon color simply do

```
<Alert color="color.error" />
```

at place where icon is implemented

Comment: It's an option, but I'm looking to change globally